# Error adding images to CImageList(MFC)

Tags: c++, mfc

I am adding images to a CImageList using the following code:

```
CImageList ImageList;

ImageList.Create(64, 64, ILC_COLOR32, 0, 1);

      Find image path and load image . . .
HBITMAP hBitmap = LoadBitmapFromFile(finder.GetFilePath(), NULL, 64, 64);

int nImage = ImageList.Add(CBitmap::FromHandle(hBitmap), RGB(0,0,0));

HBITMAP LoadBitmapFromFile(const char* pszFilePath, HDC hDC, long lMaxHeight, long lMaxWidth)
{
    // Macro that MFC needs to manage its state within a DLL
    AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState())

    // The item object which will be used to read in the file
    CxImage image;
    // Load the image from the file
    if(image.Load(pszFilePath))
    {
        ResizeImage(image, lMaxHeight, lMaxWidth);

        // Get a handle to a bitmap version of the image which the given DC can use
        return image.MakeBitmap(hDC);
    }
    return NULL;
}

void ResizeImage(CxImage& image, long lMaxHeight, long lMaxWidth)
{
    const DWORD ulImgHeight = image.GetHeight();
    const DWORD ulImgWidth = image.GetWidth();

    long nHeightDif = ulImgHeight - lMaxHeight;
    long nWidthDif = ulImgWidth - lMaxWidth;
    if(nHeightDif > 0 || nWidthDif > 0)
    {
        double rScaleFactor = 1.0;
        if(nHeightDif > nWidthDif)
            rScaleFactor = (double)lMaxHeight / (double)ulImgHeight;
        else
            rScaleFactor = (double)lMaxWidth / (double)ulImgWidth;

        long nNewHeight = (long)(ulImgHeight * rScaleFactor);
        long nNewWidth = (long)(ulImgWidth * rScaleFactor);

        image.Resample2(nNewWidth, nNewHeight);
    }
}
```

The Add method appears to add the image but will repeatedly return the same index value for the new image.  When the image list is displayed in a list box, the same image appears for all images that were added and returned the same index, but the filename appearing below the image on the list is correct.

I have tried several things to determine wnat is happening all to no avail.  This problem does not appear to be tied to the image size, or shape (h. vs. w.).  I have verified that the correct image is attached to the HBITMAP that the image is loaded onto by displaying the image on a picture control, but the image on the list control is incorrect.

If I add the images using:

```
int nImage = ImageList.Add(CBitmap::FromHandle(hBitmap), (CBitmap *)NULL);
```

none of the duplicated images are loaded.  Instead of the repeating index Add returns -1.  I can find no documentation for the errors on a CImageList.  Does anyone know what might be happening?

Comment: Are you sure that the HBITMAP you're adding is 32bpp? What happens if you use `ILC_COLOR24`? Also, what dimension is the HBITMAP? Is it 64x64 or does it contain multiple images?

Comment: I've tried both ILC_COLOR24 and ILC_COLORDDB, the result is the same.  All of the bitmaps are sisngle images.  Most are not 64X64, they are varying sizes, but there doesn't seem to be any relationship between the size of the image and the failure.  I will take another look at the failure in relation to the image size and see if I can see any parallels.

Comment: I just looked at the code again; the images are being scaled to 64X64 when they are loaded from disk, and display properly at that size when displayed in a picture control temporarily during the load and store operation.

Comment: That's good - it's ok to have integral multiples of expected width (i.e. > 1 images) but height should match the specified size. Can you post more code? For example the loading and resizing?

Comment: The images are loaded using the CxImage library. Code follows:HBITMAP LoadBitmapFromFile(const char* pszFilePath, HDC hDC, long lMaxHeight, long lMaxWidth)
{
 // Macro that MFC needs to manage its state within a DLL
 AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState())

 // The item object which will be used to read in the file
 CxImage image;
 // Load the image from the file
 if(image.Load(pszFilePath))
 {
  ResizeImage(image, lMaxHeight, lMaxWidth);

  // Get a handle to a bitmap version of the image which the given DC can use
  return image.MakeBitmap(hDC);
 }
 return NULL;
}

Comment: Resizing:void ResizeImage(CxImage& image, long lMaxHeight, long lMaxWidth){const DWORD ulImgHeight = image.GetHeight();const DWORD ulImgWidth = image.GetWidth();long nHeightDif = ulImgHeight - lMaxHeight;long nWidthDif = ulImgWidth - lMaxWidth;if(nHeightDif > 0 || nWidthDif > 0)
{
double rScaleFactor = 1.0;
if(nHeightDif > nWidthDif)
rScaleFactor = (double)lMaxHeight / (double)ulImgHeight;
else
rScaleFactor = (double)lMaxWidth / (double)ulImgWidth;
long nNewHeight = (long)(ulImgHeight * rScaleFactor);long nNewWidth = (long)(ulImgWidth * rScaleFactor);
image.Resample2(nNewWidth, nNewHeight);
}}

Comment: Sorry, I can't get the code into a readable format.

Comment: Edited the original question to add the new code.

Comment: Problem solved. I was wrong about my initial assessment that shape did not matter.  If the image is higher than it is wide it will fail to load onto the image list properly.  thanks for inspiring me to take another looke at that.